# Why is Windows 10 claiming my Microsoft-managed user account password is wrong?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, password-recovery, microsoft

I'm having some PC issues, so I've been attempting to reset my Windows installation via the advanced startup settings. Problem is, this requires you to log in to your Windows account. My Windows account is my Microsoft account, meaning, as far as I know, that they share the same password. However, when I try to log in using my Microsoft account (and any other password I recall using), I'm told the password is wrong.

I've completely changed my Microsoft account password, and still Windows is not accepting that password as the password for my user account. This is not a local account. What exactly can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Better to change your password at Microsoft Live.

Go here:   [Forgot Password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/reset-a-forgotten-microsoft-account-password-eff4f067-5042-c1a3-fe72-b04d60556c37)

Go to Microsoft Live Forgot Password.

Reset your password at Microsoft Live and then that password will be valid for the Microsoft Account on your computer.

If you are having issues with multiple accounts that Microsoft Live cannot resolve, back up your system, reset the Live Password again, then install Windows fresh with just one account.

Comment: These appear to be the same accounts. It uses the same password as my "Microsoft account," and resetting the password has not allowed me to log in to Windows with that password.

Comment: Try making a new User Account on the PC as a Microsoft Account. Something appears to be screwed up.  If this is successful you may to to reinstall with the new account.  Can you remove (delete) the duplicate account?

Comment: Assuming you have backups, reset your password, install Windows fresh and just have one Account - that should work

Comment: @Craig Mu money is on you confusing a local account that *looks* like the same as another Microsoft account  but isn't actually the same account, not an online account, just a good ol' local account that obviouslñy isn't affected by resetting/changing the password for the Microsoft account that looks similar.

Comment: The only way it can be an online account that isn't accepting the new password is you not having a proper internet connection at the time you're trying to login.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Password hash is cached, being disconnected from the internet, shouldn’t cause this issue.

Comment: @Ramhound Unless the OP changed it from somewhere else as it seems to be the case, perhaps while troubleshooting other stuff (another question posted at the same time as this one).